# Cost of using references to namespaces you don't need in C#

Tags: performance

Is there any significant cost to using a reference to a namespace you don't need? I'm thinking the members probably live on the heap somewhere, tying up memory. The reason I ask is because I noticed some old references I no longer need in some production code and am wondering if it is worth refactoring in the short term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not at all.

Namespaces and `using` statements are a purely compile-time construct.
At runtime, all references to classes and members refer to the actual member including the full namespace.
Extra `using` statements will have a minute impact on compile time, since the compiler will need to search more namespaces for each classname.

Unused *assemblies* also have no impact; assemblies aren't loaded until they're used.